# Numpy delete more rows than expected

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to separate some rows from numpy array.
Shape of array X

```
(81, 9, 3072)
```

I did

```
Xt=X[56:62,:,:]
```

shape of Xt is

```
(6, 9, 3072)
```

i delete Xt from X

```
X1=np.delete(X,Xt,axis=0)
```

Now X1 shape is

```
(67, 9, 3072)
```

should not it be

```
(75, 9, 3072)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.delete` wants a slice or an array of indexes to delete. You're not giving it either unless by luck `Xt` holds these indexes.

One option is to use a [`numpy.s_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) to get a slice object of what you want. Something like:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.ones([81, 9, 3072])
sl = np.s_[56:62]

Xt = X[sl]

X1=np.delete(X,sl,axis=0)

print(Xt.shape)
#(6, 9, 3072)

print(X1.shape)
#(75, 9, 3072)
```